# How do I make Emacs show blank spaces?

Tags: emacs, whitespace

How can I make Emacs show blank spaces (like a space, a tab, a line-jump, etc). Many other editors like Kate and Eclipse have this feature and I find it very useful to see when code is indent-broken because of mix of spaces and tabs (particularly Python).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[WhiteSpace](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) mode is an Emacs minor mode for visualizing all white space characters in the current buffer. It can be activated with `M-x whitespace-mode`.

Here is a screenshot of WhiteSpace in action taken directly from the Emacs wiki,

[image: whitespace mode in action]

Note: WhiteSpaceMode has now replaced BlankMode

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot and the link, but you forgot to actually tell us how to turn that feature on. (It's `M-x whitespace-mode` btw.)

Answer (score 5):

All the possible settings to do that seem to be [summarized here (blank-mode)](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BlankMode) and here [and here (ShowWhiteSpace)](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowWhiteSpace)

also:

```
(if (>= emacs-major-version 22)
  (progn
    ;; Mode to use with Emacs 22
    ;; http://emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BlankMode
    (require 'blank-mode)
    ;; Mode not active by default: let's activate it
    (global-blank-mode t)
    ;; ... activate it when text mode where color syntax is not active by default
    (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'blank-mode-on)
    ;; All invisible chars are shown, except newline char.
    (setq blank-chars '(tabs spaces trailing lines space-before-tab))
    ;; Show only for one color, no mark inserted
    (setq blank-style '(color))
    ;; Use for normal space (not shown)
    (set-face-background 'blank-space-face nil)
    (set-face-foreground 'blank-space-face "black")
    ;; used for non breakable space
    (set-face-background 'blank-hspace-face "PaleGreen")
    (set-face-foreground 'blank-hspace-face "black")
    ;; Used for spaces left of a tab
    (set-face-background 'blank-space-before-tab-face "orange")
    (set-face-foreground 'blank-space-before-tab-face "black")
    ;; Used for tab
    (set-face-background 'blank-tab-face "lemonchiffon")
    (set-face-foreground 'blank-tab-face "black")
    ;; used for extra space at the end of a line
    (set-face-background 'blank-trailing-face "gold")
    (set-face-foreground 'blank-trailing-face "black")
    ;; Used for line too long
    (set-face-background 'blank-line-face "snow2")
    (set-face-foreground 'blank-line-face "black")
  )
  (progn
    ;; For older Emacs prior to version 22.
    ;; http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/show-wspace.el
    (require 'show-wspace)
    (add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'show-ws-highlight-tabs)
    (add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'show-ws-highlight-hard-spaces)
    (add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'show-ws-highlight-trailing-whitespace)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

indent-broken? - never use tabs in your code - disk space is cheap these days.

Put `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` in your .emacs file. Get used to typing `C-x h M-x untabify` to untabify the entire buffer. To search for tabs type `C-s C-i`. If you have obscure control characters in your buffers you can see them with `M-x hexl-mode`.

Also `C-x h M-x indent-region` will indent the entire buffer. Some modes like vhdl-mode have a beautify region command.

Comment: Different developers on my team have different preferences for tabwidth. Setting everything to spaces screws up the rest of the team.


Thanks for playing, though.

Comment: Just for the record:
it should be `C-h f untabify`
instead of
`C-x h M-x untabify`

Comment: Emacs is good for other kinds of files (like, say, tab-delimited data files), not just code! Neat, huh?

Comment: @To1ne `C-h f untabify`: help about `untabify`. `C-x h M-x untabify`: mark the buffer, then run `untabify`.