# How to change the color of empty lines at the end of a buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, colors, buffer

I am currently using

```
(setq-default indicate-empty-lines t)
(when (not indicate-empty-lines)
    (toggle-indicate-empty-lines))
```

in my `.emacs` to indicate when a file has ended. It places a small character in the left fringe when there is not a line.

Is there a way to use Emacs' [WhiteSpace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) to change the color in the buffer to say `#3c3f41` for where there are not lines similarly to how the `while` does it with the character?

To be clearer, here is a image breakdown:

**Before**

[image: before]

**After**

[image: after]

In the after image I also removed the while statement in place of the [WhiteSpace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) one.

I guess this could be achieved some other way without [WhiteSpace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace), but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293761/how-do-i-make-emacs-show-blank-spaces) Stack Overflow question makes me think that [WhiteSpace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) is needed.

I would like to add the [WhiteSpace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) statement to my `.emacs` also.

Comment: No, I do not believe this is possible with Emacs.  The fringe coloration is the only option for empty lines at the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs is shipped with WhiteSpace, so the installation should be all ready to go.  To get the customization you want, just add the following to your .emacs:

```
(global-whitespace-mode 1)                       ; turn it on for all buffers
(set-face-background 'whitespace-empty "#3c3f41") ; set the color you want
```

This made the change you asked for with the default settings for WhiteSpace.